# Some problems using a DataTable connected with a DataGridView after sorting

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, datatable

I use a DataTable filled from a DB table and have to show it as a DataGridView where I use the DataTable as DataSource.
Unfortunately I have to reorder the rows of that DataTable according to some entries in the DataGridView.
Ordering the rows in the DataTable works well. I Use a Lambda expression with LINQ.
But when showing the DataGridView after sorting the DataTable does not show the correct order of the rows.
I tried also some other approaches. For example the detour via a DataView. Using this the sorting works and the
DataGridView shows the correct order of rows. But after this procedure, inputs in the DataGridView no longer end up in the DataTable.

As an addition to the original question, here is what I did to solve my problem.
Since the 'Community Bot' didn't understand maybe a few lines of program are missing. I'll try to deliver them here. Starting point is a DataGridView. Their DataSource is a DataTable. The DataTable is populated from a database. Later, DataRows will be added programmatically. The rows of the DataTable are then reordered using LINQ:

```
dtTable = dtTable.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(r => r.Field<Int64>("Col1")).CopyToDataTable().
```

Subsequent entries in the DGV then no longer end up in the DataTable. The connection between DGV and DataTable as DataSource no longer exists after the assignment.
Then the modified DataTable was reassigned as a datasource of the DGV:

```
BindingSource newBindingSource = new BindingSource();
MyDGV.DataSource = newBindingSource;
newBindingSource.DataSource = dtTable;
```

Subsequently, entries in the DGV end up back in the DataTable.

Regards H. Pradella

Comment: Could you give us a bit of your code?

Comment: How about ordering your data through your query? select * from table order by [column]

Answer (score 1):

But now really an answer.
Thank you so much for trying to help me.
I probably couldn't describe my problem well enough.
I also find it difficult to generate a code fragment that is as short as possible which describes the problem sufficiently clearly.
In the meantime, I have been able to solve the problem myself. Probably not on the optimal way, but the program now does what it is supposed to.
The reason for the problem is probably the assignment of the DataTable after sorting.
After sorting using LINQ, I have now reassigned the DataTable to the DGV (i.e. remap BindingSource) and then get the result I expected.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).